# Get value of a table cell whose id is the value of a variable

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<select id="pay">
  <option id="btc">Bitcoin</option>
</select>
<select id="buy">
  <option id="eur">Euro</option>
</select>
```

```js
var buy = $('#buy option:selected').attr('id');
var pay = $('#pay option:selected').attr('id');
var amount = buy + pay;
```

Now I have a table cell which has an `id` which is equal to `eurbtc`. I am trying to get the value of a table cell with its `id` like this:

```
cell = $("#" + buypay).text();
```

However I don't get anything. Please help me with this.

Comment: Are you looking for `$("#" + buy + pay).val()`?

Comment: You have a `buy` and a `pay` variable, but you don't have a `buypay` variable. Did you want to look for an element whose ID is `buy + pay` (`amount`), one of the variables, or some other combination?

Comment: @Satpal  no actually  `$("#" + buy + pay).text()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your title you seem to imply that the `#eurbtc` element is a table cell. In which case your use of `val()` is incorrect as `td` do not have a `value` attribute. Instead, you need to use `text()`.

Also, you need to use either `'#' + amount` or `'#' + buy + pay` in the selector. Try this:

```
var cell = $('#' + amount).text();
```